# Guidance related to Paypal Integration Using Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, paypal

I need some guidance related to PayPal Integration. It's not similar to a regular cart.
After checkout, the site offers a form for payment option. Either it's PayPal, or some other payment process. The form directs to controller after the user submits. An array exists, which contains all item values.

From here on how can I proceed to the Paypal site?

Answer (score 6):

Just to let you know that we've just open-sourced our replacement [CodeIgniter PayPal library](https://github.com/orderly/codeigniter-paypal-ipn), called codeigniter-paypal-ipn. (We use this library in production.)

It performs more validation than PayPal_Lib, and it also saves the orders down to your database (using either CI active record or Doctrine).

I hope you find it useful!

Comment: Hey @Alex, does your library support the same method of buy it now buttons and splitting of payments to multiple accounts?

Comment: Hi Mike - buy it now buttons should be fine - they're just a different (simpler) way of populating the cart. Splitting payments - I think you need the Adaptive Payments API for that, which is out of scope of an IPN handler... Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

There is an existing library for integration with Paypal using CodeIgniter:

http://codeigniter.com/wiki/PayPal_Lib/

Comment: I have not used the library, but it is small enough to read through and understand the functionality.

Answer (score 2):

I asked the [same kind of question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698004/suggestions-for-gateway-please)

And http://www.phpfour.com/blog/2009/02/php-payment-gateway-library-for-paypal-authorizenet-and-2checkout/ is good resource.

Please have a look.