# Suggestions for gateway please

Tags: php, mysql, gateway

I almost completed my first shopping cart with Codeigniter(PHP/MySQL).

I want to connect to payment systems. I've never developed a shopping cart before. I do not have any intention to develop my own gateway and I don't have any knowledge and skills to do it.

Could anyone give me suggestions about the best way to connect my shopping cart to payment system please?

I live in Norway, so google checkout does not work for me. It is only for UK and USA.

I need some directions and guidance what I should do.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't hard-code for one solution; they could change prices or policies at any time, making your business difficult.  Instead, use a payment gateway abstraction library, such as this one:

http://www.phpfour.com/blog/2009/02/php-payment-gateway-library-for-paypal-authorizenet-and-2checkout/